# How to point camera to 3d sphere at x,y position

Tags: 3d, geometry, webgl

I'm trying to center a webGL sphere to a specific x,y point. I can already position the globe using the Spherical Coordinates (setting the `phi` and `theta`), but I first need to convert x, y coordinates to this system (to the `phi` and `theta`). The globe is a sphere of [this image](http://mikevanrossum.nl/stuff/globe/img/earth_atmos_2048.jpg) and I can easily map lat, long to a position on that map myself (using a mapper function).

So in total what I want is:

```
convert lat/long to x/y position
convert x/y to phi/theta <-- can't figure out how to do this
position globe to the new phi/theta
```

Here is an example to see what I mean:

http://mikevanrossum.nl/stuff/globe/

Using the controls in the white box you can increase the `phi` and `theta` and you see it rotate. I am unable to come up with a way to map those numbers to positions on the image. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: helpful? http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SphericalCoords.aspx

Comment: Thanks, looking at it. Though I Don't think I'm able to figure it out based on math formulas. Also I'm not sure how I can get the "cylindrical coordinates" they are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define where the midpoint of the sphere falls.  I'm not an expert on webGL or other standards, but I do know how three dimensional renderings work.

From what I can tell, you have a sphere defined by vertices of a radius, a zenith angle and an azimuth angle.  That's a decent enough way to define a sphere.  A quick check of wikipedia will give you an in-depth explanation of spherical coordinates.  Basically as defined, the zenith angle gives you the angle between the point, the origin and the z-axis and the azimuth will indicate the angle around the z-axis.

My preference is to use i, j, k and r, theta, phi.  Truth be told, the most important consideration for these types of applications is the underlying mathematical representations, which means at bare minimum you have to either implement or link to a quaternion type and ideally, you would also include a library that handles matrix transforms and anything else between the binding in a linear algebra text.

If you understand what the API is doing from the standpoint of the underlying math it's a really simple operation.  First we have a midpoint for the globe -- in your case it will look like 0, 0, z (or k).  In general, if we use a simplified point conversion model it can be found that with the camera at 0, 0, 0 facing toward positive z (or k), as it has been mentioned many times before, you will end up dividing both the x (or i) and y (or j) by z (or k).  (i.e. x'=x/z; y'=y/z)

The radius of the globe in world coordinates will correspond to a a value r'=r/z since for most displays the pixels are arranged orthogonally and that will be the visible radius of the sphere.  You will have to adjust the frame of view if you do move the globe off of the z axis, since if you have a relatively large radius in world coordinates, the sphere will become oval.

The best way to do correct this is to shrink it down by a certain scale and then zoom in by that same scale.  So then the radius still appears to be r, but we've divided it by a certain scale in world coordinates, before we generate the sphere.  Then once the sphere has been generated with radius r/scale in world coordinates, we have to multiply by that scale in x' and y' so that x' = scale * x/z and y' = scale * y/z.  I'm assuming you know how to center the image on the frame.

If you don't scale down the radius of the sphere by about two significant digits and zoom in by a similar amount the sphere will appear stretched and oval at the edges of the viewing window.  If you still need the angles between the x coordinate and the yz plane and the y coordinate and the xz plane, that would be something like atan2 or arctan2(x, z) and (y, z), where there are two parameters in the function to avoid the divide by zero. You still don't want to be rendering anything with a z value of zero though.

Another way to determine an angle in three dimensional space is to take the xyz coordinate of A and B, calculate the dot product between them and divide by the product of the norms; this will give you the cosine of the angle between A and B via the origin.  I omitted the arccos operation in my function since it is also used in Phong shading.

To get the phi, theta from the x, y you have to know the radius and the distance of the midpoint from the camera, which works out to zenith angles between pi/2 and pi and azimuth angles between 0 and 2pi.  If you build a square around the sphere, and go line by line, ( i.e. a raytracer) you have to check if each point is in the final circle of radius r' which will work out to be r/(scale * z)  z being the z coordinate of the midpoint.

If we are in the circle, the we will define an angle -- the azimuth will be the angle around the center of the circle and the zenith will be the angle between the point on the surface of the sphere at said x, y coordinate and the surface point between the camera and the midpoint via the midpoint of the sphere.  Which, if you use the angle operation I mentioned, becomes a simple task.

I'm on this phase of a project myself.

Bottom line: You need to brush up on your trig -- it's an absolute requirement, no matter what API you are using.